# When access CloudStack UI got HTTP Status 404 error

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404, cloudstack

I have installed CloudStack Management Server followed this guide:

http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/projects/cloudstack-installation/en/4.9/management-server/index.html

## Versions

- CloudStack: 4.9
- CentOS: 6.8

Finally I start server:

```
# cloudstack-setup-management
Starting to configure CloudStack Management Server:
Configure Firewall ...        [OK]
Configure CloudStack Management Server ...[OK]
CloudStack Management Server setup is Done!
```

And accessed it from browser:

```
http://192.168.33.101:8080/client
```

I got this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - 
type Status report
message
description The requested resource () is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like apache is unable to connect to Cloudstack database.
Please check if mysql service is running and csm is pointing to correct database server.

you can reinitialize database:

```
# cloudstack-setup-databases cloud:<dbpassword>@localhost --deploy-as=root:<password>
```

then start management server:

```
# cloudstack-setup-management
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.